# Android: Call methods to each other and to display messages

Tags: java, android

I have this code and what I want to do is to be calling the two methods together, but I need to be able to visualize the messages. This code does the execution, but I do not see the messages because the program is never finished running. How to stop the program momentarily so that the messages are displayed and then resume the code? I tried it with Thread.sleep and with sleep, but I'm just sleeping the program and the messages are not displayed.

public void monitoreo(){

```
try{

   estado_comparacion= estado_actual;
   while (comparacion()) {
       ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
       if (rs.next()) {
           estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
       }
   }
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
public boolean comparacion() {

if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}else{
    estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    a=0;
    return  true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about using handler.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showMessage("msg1");
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showMessage("msg2");
        }
    }, 1000);

}

public void showMessage(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Comment: But, I try wiht this.